# Laravel 5.6 - Laravel Excel 3.1 import пустая строка

Tags: laravel, excel

При импорте таблицы  excel в БД MySql добавляется пустая строка. Например в таблице excel 10 записей, при импорте добавляется 10 записей с id от 1 до 10 и 11я запись - пустая строка с id 11. Подскажите как сделать, чтобы пустая строка не добавлялась!? Зарнее благадарю

Код контроллера ExcelController.php

```
class ExcelController extends Controller
{
  public function import() {
    if (!request()->file('file')){
      return back()->with('warning', 'Не выбран файл для загрузки!');
    } else {
      Excel::import(new UsersImport, request()->file('file'));
      return back()->with('success', 'БД успешно обновлена!');
    }
  }
}
```

Код Модели UserImport.php

```
class UsersImport implements ToModel
{
    /**
     * @param array $row
     *
     * @return User|null
     */

  public function model(array $row)
  {

    $InsertOrUpdate = User::updateOrCreate(
      ['test_sum'  => $row[7]],
      ['col_1'   => $row[1],
      'col_2'    => $row[0],
      'col_3'    => $row[5],
      'col_4'    => bcrypt($row[6]),
      'col_5'    => $row[2],
      'col_6'    => $row[3],
      'col_7'    => $row[4],
      'col_8'    => $row[7],
    ]);
  }
}
```

Comment: Не совсем по теме, но первое, что бросается в глаза - это валидация наличия файла. Вынесите её в Request, код чище станет, это хорошая практика.

Comment: Если по теме, то как вариант, проверять, заполнены ли поля в строке через if, если заполнены, то записывать в бд

Comment: @ Alexxosipov я новичок, не могли-бы вы привести пример? if ($row[1] == ''){ return back()} else {$InsertOrUpdate = User::updateOrCreate(
      ['test_sum'  => $row[7]],
      ['col_1'   => $row[1],]); }  }     Примерно так?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вообщем добавил проверку, и строк пустых не стало

```
public function model(array $row)
  {
    if (!empty($row[7])){
    $InsertOrUpdate = User::updateOrCreate(
      ['test_sum'     => $row[7]],
       ['col_1'   => $row[1],
        'col_2'    => $row[0],
        'col_3'    => $row[5],
        'col_4'    => bcrypt($row[6]),
        'col_5'    => $row[2],
        'col_6'    => $row[3],
        'col_7'    => $row[4],
        'col_8'    => $row[7],
       ]);
    }
  }
```